# Giving my ContextMenu style treatment not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF App and I have a context menu showing up when I right click on any row in my datagrid. It works 100% but I want to mess with the style and give a nice dark theme to this context menu. This was my first ever attempt at making a context menu in dark theme.

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Resources>
 ...
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF484848" Foreground="White">
                        <MenuItem Header="Item 1" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF484848">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Foo.Bar.MyAwesomeApp;component/Resources/icon-1.png"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Item 2" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF484848">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Foo.Bar.MyAwesomeApp;component/Resources/icon-2.png"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <Separator Background="#FF131313" Height="2" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Item 3" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF484848">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="/Foo.Bar.MyAwesomeApp;component/Resources/icon-3.png"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
<DataGrid.Columns>
   ...
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

All this is getting me is a context menu with the desired background color but the icon area has a light gray background taking over the icon space and when I hover over each menu item I still get the old light gray colors. In addition there's a vertical light gray bay between the icon space and the header text space and I have no idea how to change the style for that.

Has anyone been able to solve this issue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own MenuItem.Template, you can copy default WPF template and change it.

Default template is

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background" Color="#0A000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border" Color="#21000000"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Background}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Border}" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentSource="Header" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

You can get it if you click on menuitem element in xaml designer, and select Edit Template as a Copy

Comment: where is that default template?

Comment: I added default template and information how you can get it to my answer.

Comment: so I notice that there's this light gray background just behind the icon space. Also, there are two verticals lines that appear at either side of the icon space as well. Any idea how to do away with these with your default template?

Comment: You need to edit this default template and remove line and set your background, then apply this template to your menu items.